# Android link to external store

Tags: android, paypal, in-app-purchase, payment-gateway, credit-card

My problem is not so much a programming question but figured 
someone here could help me out with that

Is it possible to send a link from my app to an external online store?
I already have an online store running on the web
and i would not like to implement it all over again, just to send a link to it
so the users can make the purchase on a web browser / webview.

I seems like there might be a legal problem with this since google 
wants me to make all in app purchases through them.

If anyone knows the answer or a place explaining this issue it would be great!

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ofcourse you can do that. Google allows a way for In App purchasing, it means, you don't have to worry of security etc, as Google manages all of it. Its your wish to implement your own purchasing mechanism. And yes, you can redirect the user to a online store of a particular item, by starting the browser Intent, or web view and the user can purchase there.

Let me know if you have any more doubts.

Comment: Thanks for the very quick reply!! Thats all i needed!

Comment: Then please mark nithinreddy's answer as having solved your question. :-)